# Libyuv compile meets asm error of unknown register name ‘ymm1’ in ‘asm’

Tags: assembly, cpu-registers, libyuv

Libyuv compile meets asm error of unknown register name ‘ymm1’ in ‘asm’

I tried to compile libyuv(seem to be the latest) in Ubuntu14. When I proceed to make it, there are asm related errors that stop compiling process. It reports:

```
make -j7 V=1 -f linux.mk
g++ -c -O2 -fomit-frame-pointer -Iinclude/ source/row_posix.cc -o source/row_posix.o
g++ -c -O2 -fomit-frame-pointer -Iinclude/ source/scale_mips.cc -o source/scale_mips.o
g++ -c -O2 -fomit-frame-pointer -Iinclude/ source/scale_posix.cc -o source/scale_posix.o
g++ -c -O2 -fomit-frame-pointer -Iinclude/ source/video_common.cc -o source/video_common.o
source/row_posix.cc: In function ‘void libyuv::CopyRow_AVX(const uint8*, uint8*, int)’:
source/row_posix.cc:3290:4: error: unknown register name ‘ymm1’ in ‘asm’
   );
    ^
source/row_posix.cc:3290:4: error: unknown register name ‘ymm0’ in ‘asm’
make: *** [source/row_posix.o] 错误 1
```

What’s wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you aren't doing anything to pass `-mavx` to the compiler. `ymm*` are AVX-256 registers.

Comment: Where shall I add it? [link](http://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/Getting-Started) . According to it , I can't find where to add.